# Uploadify with NodeJS | Post parameters not being sent

Tags: file-upload, node.js, uploadify, express

I'm building my latest app using nodeJS and need to be able to upload multiple files. I have chosen to use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) flash based file uploader.

Unfortunately the 'scriptData' vars don't seem to be being sent. Usual method of retrieval of POST vars in node looks like `var postDataValue = req.body.postDataKey;` but with Uploadify the req.body object is empty.

Hope someone can help with this.

Comment: hi how do u use uploadify with express, i saw the file in uploadify is written in php not js,so how can i use uploadify in express.js

Answer (score 0):

I had to send the parameters via query string in the end. Must be something to do with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Node.js. req.body is not part of node. It's built into BodyParser and provided by Connect. Mainly used in Express.

See http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html

If you don't use it, the req.body object should be empty.